# how to set JAVA_HOME in Websphere Application server 8.5

Tags: java, websphere

Since WAS 8.5 is by default shipped with IBM JDK6, I have installed IBM JDK7 using the Installation Manager

But when I run my application, it's taking the IBM JDK6 instead of JDK7

Can someone please let me know how to set JAVA_HOME to take the JDK7 instead of JDK6

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the documented [`managesdk`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/rxml_managesdk.html) command.

Comment: Here is more detailed description, [Java 7 in IBM WebSphere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25223414/3701228)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the SDK used by the server from the web console: select your server on the web console, then on the right, click on "java SDKs" and select the one you want

Answer (score -2):

Take a look inside setupCmdLine.bat/sh file in your WAS installation directory.
As far as I remember you should be able to set JAVA_HOME directly (e.g. JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\WebSphere\AppServer\java or JAVA_HOME=C:\MyJDK)

Answer (score -2):

Yes Maciej,

I believe i could setupCmdLine.bat would help here.

Thanks,
Kusuma

Comment: Found setupsdk.bat in the path C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer3\bin\sdk where JAVA_HOME is being set.

Comment: Found setupsdk.bat in the path C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer3\bin\sdk where JAVA_HOME is being set. I have set JAVA_HOME. But what about path "JAVA_NATIVE_LIB_DIR" .Does the dlls present here depends on jdk which is set(C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer3\lib\native\win\x86_64)?