# Websphere Application Server 8.5 Java 7 questions

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-8

I have the following questions on WAS 8.5 installation:

1. Can Java 7 be installed outside {or}c:\IBM\Websphere\Appserver
2. Can the Java 7 name be other than Java1.7_64?

Also how to get the info. using any bat/sh file from IBM

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please be aware: Tags are not keywords.  Tagging this question with `websphere`, `application` and `server` does not mean you're talking about the Websphere Application Server.  Each tag stands alone; `websphere` alone was enough.

Comment: For full profile with Java 7, also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098604/how-to-set-java-home-in-websphere-application-server-8-5?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No to both: there is no way to change the Java install directory.

To determine the configured JDK, source setupCmdLine and use the JAVA_HOME variable.  For example, on UNIX:

```
. /path/to/profile/setupCmdLine.sh
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

...and on Windows:

```
C:\path\to\profile\bin\setupCmdLine.bat
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

If you need to automate discovery, you might write a temporary batch file with the following contents, execute it (e.g., using ProcessBuilder), and then parse the resulting output:

```
@echo off
call "C:\path\to\profile\bin\setupCmdLine.bat"
echo JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%
```

Comment: I haven't played a lot with 8.5 but my reading indicates that an Oracle JDK can be used on Windows (and possibly other platforms too). You are not likely to install an Oracle JDK in a WebSphere install directory. I will do some reading and get back but i wanted to hear your comments and thoughts on this space.

Comment: @Manglu The traditional profile must be used with the Java SDK that is shipped (i.e., the IBM Java SDK on Windows).  The Liberty profile can be used with any Java 6 SDK, including Oracle on Windows.