# Java 7.1 in IBM Websphere

Tags: java, websphere, java-7, websphere-8

I have Java SDK 6 in IBM websphere 8.5.5.2. Where can i download Java SDK 7.1 in IBM website and update it to websphere.

I tried google and couldn't find required information to update Java SDK 7.1. Can i update it from Installation Manager or should i download any files from IBM?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Download Java SDK 7.1 from [WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5 Fix Pack 2](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24037250).
Then unzip both archives `7.1.0.0-WS-IBMWASJAVA-part1.zip` and `7.1.0.0-WS-IBMWASJAVA-part2.zip` to folder and use Installation Manager to install new SDK. Here are [Installation instructions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.installation.base.doc/ae/tins_installation_jdk7_gui.html?lang=en).
Then use [managesdk](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/ae/rxml_managesdk.html?lang=en) command to find out sdk id and switch Java for your profile.

For example (it's from 7.0, but you will get the idea how to find it for 7.1):

```
C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\profiles\AppSrv1\bin>managesdk.bat -listAvailable
CWSDK1003I: Available SDKs :
CWSDK1005I: SDK name: 1.6_32
CWSDK1005I: SDK name: 1.7_32
CWSDK1001I: Successfully performed the requested managesdk task.
```

Then if you want to change it for one profile you invoke:

```
managesdk -enableProfile -profileName AppSrv01 -sdkname SDK_Name -enableServers
```

or for all profiles:

```
managesdk -enableProfileAll -sdkname SDK_Name -enableServers
```

Comment: Thanks! i'll try that and will get back if any issues.

Comment: My profile name is RESTServer and server is AppServer-85. I tried to invoke managesdk command and see this error                                                                             C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer-85\bin>managesdk.bat -enableProfile -RESTServer AppServer-85 -sdkname 1.7.1_64 -enableServers
CWSDK0010E: Parameter -RESTServer not valid.
CWSDK0010E: Parameter AppServer-85 not valid.
CWSDK1002I: The requested managesdk task failed. See previous messages.

Comment: I have a question. If our websphere application server' version is 7.0.0.37. How can I change java from 1.6 to 1.7. By the way, os is Windows 2008 &2012.

Comment: @saneryee You can't. Changing JDK is only allowed in WAS v8+. So if you need JDK 1.7 you would need to upgrade to WAS 8.0 or beter 8.5.5.

Comment: @saneryee Update - actually JDK 1.7 is available only starting from 8.5+, not 8.0 as I wrote. Sorry.

Comment: @Gas Thanks a lot.Maybe We will update our WAS to 8.5+, as you mention that