# Websphere jdk upgrade

Tags: java, linux, websphere

I have installed ibm jdk(1.8) in my linux system.
I have installed WebSphere ND 8.5.5.7 in the same system.
Now  I want the WebSphere  jdk to be upgraded to 1.8.
For that I need to run managesdk command.
So , I checked this link https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSWSR9_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.mdmhs.release.install.doc/Topics/InstallingJava.html
In this link it is stated that I need to have java_ folder inside my WAS home.But I have installed the jdk in a different path . So how to progress ,so that I can run managesdk command to upgrade WAS jdk ?

Comment: Are you trying to add a Oracle JDK to Websphere? Or did you install an IBM JDK?

Comment: "Super User" or "Unix & Linux" might be a better forum for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I needed to install IBM sdk through IBM installation Manager.After that run managesdk.
Now it is working.
Thanks @Alasdair for pointing out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere classic doesn't support Java 8.

Comment: It's webshere network deployment 8.5.5.7 ..are you saying jdk 1.8 won't work with it ?Even if I use jdk 1.7 how to make it available for websphere?

Comment: I'm saying that WAS classic ND 8.5.5.7 will not run with a Java 8 SDK. It isn't an install option and WAS classic ND 8.5.5.7 only runs with the Java SDKs that are installable via IBM Installation Manager. You can use Java 6 or Java 7, but there is no Java 8 option for running the WAS classic server.

Comment: OK.I will give it a try.

Comment: @AyanBiswas [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25223414/3701228) you have steps how to switch to Java 7

Comment: It seems that I needed to install IBM sdk through IBM installation Manager.