# Changing the SDK in WebSphere Application Server 8.5

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

When I try to start the the deployment manager in WebSphere Application Server I'm getting the following error:

```
00000001 SDKUtils       
A ADML0004E: An exception occurred when attempting to expand variable $(JAVA_HOME) com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.variable.
UndefinedVariableException: Undefined variable JAVA_HOME
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.VariableMapImpl.expand(VariableMapImpl.j
```

Comment: expecting linux commands

Comment: expecting more details and that you start correctly formatting your questions

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot set third party Java SDK for traditional WebSphere Application Server. For WAS 8.5.5.x you can only select from IBM Java 6 and IBM Java 7 which must be downloaded from IBM and installed via Installation Manager. So don't play with JAVA_HOME variable manually.

Once you install Java 7 for WAS, you can use `managesdk` command line tool to switch Java for given profile and server.

See also:

- [Java 7.1 in IBM Websphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223122/java-7-1-in-ibm-websphere/25223414#25223414)
- [managesdk command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rxml_managesdk.html?lang=en)

Comment: I delete the JAVA_HOME variable through console . Now i not able to start .Is their any way to set this variable again to deployment manger node ?

Comment: after setting also node and server values are null CWSDK1006I: PROFILE_COMMAND_SDK = 1.7.1_64 
CWSDK1008I: Node dmgrnode SDK name: null 
CWSDK1009I: Server dmgr SDK name: null

Comment: @DharshanSithamparam you have to write what you actually tried to invoke and with what parameters.

Answer (score 0):

since we can not start the deployment manger or default server, there is a way to solve this problem that is add the JAVA_HOME into  varibles.xml file which is under server folder. path : Installserver/profile/config/node/cell/server

Answer (score -1):

Please give some more information like OS, windows, or linux, or what.
If I understand correctly you'll use the jdk of the WAS installation elsewhere?
Under Windows set JAVA_HOME accordingly within the System environment properties. logout / login after this may be a good idea. 
Under linux use: export JAVA_HOME=/opt/ibm/pathtoWAS/java
I would do this within .profile and maybe it's helpful to set the PATH to the jdk too!

Comment: am trying in the linux server  CWSDK1004I: Profile dmgrprofile : 
CWSDK1006I: PROFILE_COMMAND_SDK = 1.7.1_64 
CWSDK1008I: Node dmgrnode SDK name: null 
CWSDK1009I: Server dmgr SDK name: null . I want to set the SDK name 
CWSDK1001I: Successfully performed the requested managesdk task. 
[wasadm@sahoinbkr02u bin]$ now i want to set the  dmgrnode ,  dmgr

Comment: Use the managesdk command as Gas is proposing. On a started server you can use the Admin Console too. You can set the default jdk under:
Application servers > server1 > Java SDKs